# Javascript Random Number Function - undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following function to generate a random number between 1 and 20 and then doubling that number. The function seems to be working, but I'm getting an undefined after the double. What's causing this?

```
function PlayGame(){

    var min = 0;
    var max = 20;

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var doubleRandom = (randomNumber * 2);

    document.write(randomNumber);
    document.write(doubleRandom);

}
```

I am calling document.write(PlayGame()) in html doc. Maybe this is my issue.

Comment: Works for me (albeit without `document.write`): http://jsfiddle.net/PXpyq/

Comment: Are you actually calling `document.write(PlayGame())`? That would make sense -- `PlayGame` returns `undefined`, and you'd be making a third call to `document.write`. You need to edit your question to provide more code so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: It work for me. I change `document.write` to `console.log`. what's your brower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Live demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/FCZJq/)

Your problem is `document.write` in this case. In addition to that, you can simplify with the following:

```
function getRandomInRange(rangeMax) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * rangeMax);
};

function print(x) {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + x + "</p>";
};

setInterval(function() {
    print(getRandomInRange(20));
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Works fine for me with `document.write`: http://jsfiddle.net/PXpyq/2/

Comment: Maybe it's in my html call:<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Random</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="random.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
document.write(PlayGame());
</script>
</body>
</html>